# Subversion on OpenSuse

Tags: linux, svn

I am trying to switch my web server from Windows to Linux. I am using OpenSuse and I am currently running it in a virtual machine to ensure that I can get everything working before I wipe my web server.

I have installed Subversion but when I try to run the svnserve service from inside yast it displays the following error:

> /etc/init.d/svnserve start returned 1 (unspecified error) :

How can I debug this error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced with that situation, I typically examine the svnserve script and run the steps manually to find out which is failing.  You may find output in /var/log/deamon.log, though.

The init.d services are not very consistent in what and where they log their output.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Found I was being a bit of a noob, and was pointing the subversion directory to the wrong location,